# Separate description and image from the rss item

Tags: asp.net, regex, rss

I have a rss feed in the format

```
<item>
<title>11/09/2012 - Coffee Roasting 101</title>
<link><![CDATA[http://test.com/helios/index.php?com=detail&eID=277478]]></link>
<description>&#60;p&#62;&#60;img style=&#34;float: right; margin: 5px;&#34; src=&#34;http://test.com/helios/img/hand.jpg&#34; alt=&#34;five finger of coffee please&#34; width=&#34;127&#34; height=&#34;132&#34; /&#62;Learn the basics of roasting coffee. What...</description>
<guid>http://test.com/helios/index.php&#63;com=detail&amp;eID=277478</guid>
<pubDate>Fri, 09 Nov 2012 08:00:00 -0800</pubDate>
</item>
```

The description node has some text as well img tag in it. Now in my function I'm doing something like:

```
foreach (ArrayList item in rssItems)
 {
string desc = (string)item[1];
-------------------           
     Response.Write("<li><a href=\"" + link + "\">" + title + "</a>");
     Response.Write("<p>" + desc+ "</p></li>");
-------------------
------------------- 

  }
```

I get a p tag with the text as well as the image with its height and width. I'm trying to get the image as a separate img tag without the attributes and description in the `<p>` tag.
Any help to approach this problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having HTML code of `<description>` tag, use regex pattern `<img.*?src="(.*?)".*?>` to find an `<img>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, now I get the description without the image. String str = "";
                str = Regex.Replace(desc, "(<img.*?src=(.*?).*?>)", "");
                Response.Write("<p>" + str + "</p></li>"); How can I get only the src?

Comment: @Vinit - Use `Regex.Match` to get match `m`, so `m.Groups[1]` will be `src` link.